# Scan line algorithm for intersecting polygons

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-geometry

Given two sets of polygons $P_1 = \{s_1,...,s_m\}$ and $P_2=\{s_m+1,...,s_n\}$ with total number of $n$ segments, the previous and next segment on it's polygon can be determined in $O(1)$. Describe a scan-line algorithm that computes all points of $P_1 \cap P_2$ in $O(n).$

Comment: *all* points? If the intersection of the interiors is not empty, there'll be an infinite number of points in it.

Comment: @lhf the algorithm looks for line intersections , since we have finite set of line segments we should have a finite set of intersecting lines.

Comment: You probably mean two polygons or two sets of edges ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust , two sets of edges , each form a polygon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm used for this can be the Bentley-Ottman algorithm, Which uses a sweep line. Visit this link for more info (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm)

Comment: This is not $O(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as the number of intersections can be $O(n^2)$.

Comment: if we try the naive approach then yes it will be $O(n^2)$

Comment: no , since we don't check all the segments against each other.

Comment: I meant it is $\Omega(n^2)$. In any case, $O(n)$ is not possible (except in constrained situations).

Comment: When there are $O(n^2)$ intersections you can't produce them faster than $O(n^2)$. Bentley-Ottman is $O((n + k)\log n)$, which is indeed $O(n^2\log n)$ in the worst case.